How to get the virtual address of a page in page cache without vma?
In a file mapped area, I can use a function like vma_address to get the virtual address of a page in the page cache.
static inline unsigned long
vma_address(struct page *page, struct vm_area_struct *vma)
{
    pgoff_t pgoff;
    unsigned long address;

    VM_BUG_ON_PAGE(PageKsm(page), page);    /* KSM page->index unusable */
    pgoff = page_to_pgoff(page);
    if (pgoff >= vma->vm_pgoff) {
        address = vma->vm_start +
            ((pgoff - vma->vm_pgoff) << PAGE_SHIFT);
        /* Check for address beyond vma (or wrapped through 0?) */
        if (address < vma->vm_start || address >= vma->vm_end)
            address = -EFAULT;
    } else if (PageHead(page) &&
           pgoff + compound_nr(page) - 1 >= vma->vm_pgoff) {
        /* Test above avoids possibility of wrap to 0 on 32-bit */
        address = vma->vm_start;
    } else {
        address = -EFAULT;
    }
    return address;
}

But I find out that when opening a file (open instead of mmap), there is no vma in address_space at all. Here is my code:
// code in driver, called by file_operations.write
// fd: the fd of a regular file opened by user program
void printFile(int fd) {
  struct fdtable *fdt;
  struct file *file;
  struct address_space *mapping;
  struct vm_area_struct *vma;
  struct page *page;
  int i;

  fdt = current->files->fdt;
  file = fdt->fd[fd];
  if (file == NULL) {
    DEBUG_PRINT(DEVICE_NAME ": &file is NULL\n");
    return;
  }

  mapping = file->f_mapping;
  if (mapping == NULL) {
    DEBUG_PRINT(DEVICE_NAME ": &address_space is NULL\n");
    return;
  }

  DEBUG_PRINT(DEVICE_NAME ": &file: %p, &address_space: %p, nrpages: %ld\n",
              file, mapping, mapping->nrpages);

  // just print root vma in address_space
  i_mmap_lock_read(mapping);
  if (mapping->i_mmap.rb_root.rb_node != NULL) {
    vma = container_of(mapping->i_mmap.rb_root.rb_node, struct vm_area_struct,
                       shared.rb);
    printOneVMA(vma);
  } else {
    DEBUG_PRINT(DEVICE_NAME ": no vma in address_space\n");
  }
  i_mmap_unlock_read(mapping);

  // print pages in address_space
  if (mapping_empty(mapping)) {
    DEBUG_PRINT(DEVICE_NAME ": i_pages in address_space is empty\n");
  } else {
    for (i = 0; i < mapping->nrpages; ++i) {
      page = xa_load(&mapping->i_pages, i);
      if (page != NULL) {
        DEBUG_PRINT(DEVICE_NAME
                    ": &page(%d): %p, &page.mapping: %p, page.index: %ld\n",
                    i, page, page->mapping, page->index);
      }
    }
  }
}

// user program
int main() {
  int fd;

  fd = open(DEVICE_PATH, O_RDWR);
  if (fd < 0) {
    perror("Failed to open the device");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  int test_fd = open("./text.txt", O_RDWR);
  if (test_fd < 0) {
    perror("Failed to open the file");
    close(fd);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  write(test_fd, "Hello, world!", 13);

  write(fd, NULL, test_fd); // will call printFile in kernel mode

  getchar();

  close(fd);
  close(test_fd);

  return 0;
}

Here is the output of dmesg:
printVMADriver: &file: 000000003f849862, &address_space: 0000000055fd35f1, nrpages: 1
printVMADriver: no vma in address_space
printVMADriver: &page(0): 00000000746bbc62, &page.mapping: 0000000055fd35f1, page.index: 0

I believe the page's virtual address is in kernel space, but I don't know how to verify it, because there is no vma. How can I get the virtual address of this page? Can anyone explain the difference between this kind of page and pages in a file mapped area?
Update:
I assume this page lies in the linear mapping area, and use the following code to get the virtual address:
#include <asm-generic/memory_model.h>

// #define page_to_virt(x)  __va(PFN_PHYS(page_to_pfn(x)))

vaddr = page_to_virt(page);
DEBUG_PRINT(DEVICE_NAME ": &page(%d).vaddr: %p\n", i, vaddr);
for (j = 0; j < 13; ++j) {
    DEBUG_PRINT(DEVICE_NAME ": page(%d).vaddr[%d]: %c\n", i, j, vaddr[j]);
}

The output is:
printVMADriver: &page(0).vaddr: 00000000d291cbf0
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[0]: H
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[1]: e
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[2]: l
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[3]: l
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[4]: o
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[5]: ,
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[6]:  
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[7]: w
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[8]: o
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[9]: r
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[10]: l
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[11]: d
printVMADriver: page(0).vaddr[12]: !

Still don't know how kernel organizes and allocates these pages.

Seems to me like you just got the virtual address using page_to_virt(). What more do you want?
